# How can the recession velocity of the galaxies be constant but the universe expand and a accelerating rate?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe, observable-universe

This almost seem  counter-intuitive to me as if a object is such as a Galaxy is moving away from me at a constant velocity and the space between us is accelerating so should the velocity. 
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Why do you think it’s constant? What happens when you differentiate $v = rH$ wrt to time?

Comment: Otherwise the calculation for the age of the universe would all be wrong

Comment: Otherwise what? I’m asking what you get for an answer when you do the computation. Here: $\dot{v} = \dot{r}H + r \dot{H}$. If space is accelerating, then $\dot{r}>0$ and $\dot{H} \geq 0$; that is, so is the recession of galaxies, $\dot{v}>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the recession velocities of galaxies aren't constant. Even if you refer to Hubble's law which is only applicable to nearby galaxies, recession velocities change with time. Recession velocity is given by:
$$v\approx \dot{d_P}=\dot{R}(t)\chi$$
where the physical distance is $\text{d}_P=R(t)\chi$, for any 2 co-moving galaxies $\chi$ remains constant. Finally:
$$v \approx \frac{\dot{R}(t )}{R(t)} d_P = H(t) d_P$$
Hubble's constant $H(t)=\frac{\dot{R}(t )}{R(t)}$ changes with time. This we can see from the Friedmann equations implying $v$ varies with time.

But since the change in time will be very less if we compare for example a year with the age of the universe, change in $R(t)$ in a year won't be much. Thus, we can assume that $v$ remains constant within that time scale (but again an approximation).